# Ember Collapsible Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Ember.js with handlebars and I need to make a div within my page collapse/expand when clicked. I know how to do this in jQuery, but I can't use any jQuery. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Also I don't want to just toggle a hide attribute, I need the full sliding up and down feature for collapsing. If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ember.js, but are you trying to achieve something like this? http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/yidab

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm trying to model http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html (Just with better styling). I just need to find a way to do it with ember. I'm presuming I need to use an ember view to do it. Also I need to put a dynamic view (maybe an outlet... i think) as the contents of the collapsible container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on your view will cause a click event to be triggered. You can code your animation in any manner you want inside a click event handler in your view:

```
CollapsableView = Ember.View.extend({
   click : function(event) {
      this.$().toggle('fast');
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this in Ember is via the awesome [Liquid Fire](http://ef4.github.io/liquid-fire/#/) addon.

The outline:

1. Install Liquid Fire into your project.
2. Define a transition like this:

   ```
   this.transition(
     this.hasClass('transition-spoiler'),
     this.toValue(true),
     this.use('toDown'),
     this.reverse('toUp')
   );
   ```
3. In your controller/component, create a property `spoilerIsVisible` and a `toggleSpoiler` property:

   ```
   spoilerIsVisible: false,

   actions: {
     toggleSpoiler: function() {
       this.toggleProperty('spoilerIsVisible');
     }
   }
   ```
4. In your page/component template, create a button and a spoiler wrapper like this:

   ```
   <button {{action 'toggleSpoiler'}}>
     {{if spoilerIsVisible 'Show spoiler' 'Hide spoiler'}}
   </button>

   {{#liquid-if spoilerIsVisible class="transition-spoiler"}}
     <p>Dumbledore dies</p>
   {{/liquid-if}}
   ```

Note that you can wrap steps 3-4 into an `x-spoiler` component or something.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, but with a tree-structure. I have written a blog post about this previously here: http://haagen-software.no/blog/post/2012-05-05-Ember_tree

It has the features you need in it, in that it adds and removed elements from the DOM when the nodes are clicked on.

A working example can be seen in an app I am currently building here: https://github.com/joachimhs/EurekaJ/tree/netty-ember/EurekaJ.View/src/main/webapp